# Joomla! empty RCPT

Tags: iis, joomla, smtp

I'm working with a Joomla! component that uses the JFactory::getMailer() to send confirmation emails.

The PHP code looks something like this:

```
$mail->addRecipient( 'admin@mydomain.com' );
$mail->setSender( array( $MailFrom, $FromName ) );
$mail->setSubject( $FromName.': '.$subject );
$mail->setBody( $body );
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$sent = $mail->Send();
```

However, the log file shows the following:

```
+FROM:<customerservice@otherdomain.com>
+TO:<admin@mydomain.com>
+TO:<>
+TO:<>
```

As a result of the empty TO addresses, we're getting a 501 and the email(s) are not getting sent.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using Joomla 1.6/1.7, do you get the same results with `JUtility::sendMail()`?   http://docs.joomla.org/JUtility::sendMail/1.6

Comment: Not sure ... this is Joomla 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUtility::sendMail() is the preferred way to send mail. Can you try using that and post the results ?

Comment: SMTP Error! The following recipients failed:
PHPMAILER_RECIPIENTS_FAILED,

Comment: I can't tell for sure, yet, but I'm beginning to believe there may be an issue with the recipient array.  Is there any way you're aware of to clear the recipients before we add the recipient?

Comment: If you use JUtility::sendMail() there is no need to 'clear' the recipient array. Seems like you are using SMTP, so make sure if your recipients are not empty and your server does not have any kind of issues like rate limits etc. Check the following forum post for the specific error you are getting. - http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1984707

Comment: Turns out the problem was two-fold.  First, we switched to JUtility::sendMail() as suggested, but continued to have problems.  Then, we learned that our mail server was not specified correctly in the configuration.php (GoDaddy hosted Exchange).  Thanks for the help!